# Changed Wordpress table prefix, I'm not an administrator any more

Tags: wordpress

After a series of malware being uploaded to my wordpress I followed some instructions to change my table prefixes from the `wp_` default.

- I changed the prefixes of the table names in phpMyAdmin.
- Changed the prefix in `wp_config`
- Changed the prefixes in the user_meta table for the `capabilities` and `user_level` key.

However, I can no longer edit pages, publish new pages, nor change the theme (`Only the current theme is available to you. Contact the administrator for information about accessing additional themes.`)

My capabilities in the database are `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}` User level is 10.
I'm clearly not an administrator any more, would appreciate any ideas on how I can fix this!

Wordpress 3.5.1

I have a database backup so can undo this if I can't make it work, but I'd rather make it work. I followed the guide here:

http://tdot-blog.com/wordpress/6-simple-steps-to-change-your-table-prefix-in-wordpress

Comment: I would suggest to restore the database and use a plugin like http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-security-scan/ to do the job.

Comment: I've also backed up the disk files so I'll try this plugin, I might have another go at following the guide first, maybe I missed a step. Thanks @RRikesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total user error, I had a typo when renaming the `wp_user_roles` row in the `wp_options` table.